# The official library for work with ethereum payments

Tags: go-ethereum, wallets, python, pyethereum, golang

I looking for way to generate ether wallet (priv-pub pair), handle incoming transaction to that wallet and make/push to network transaction from it.

How to do that via go-ethereum or pyethereum (full node sync via geth is in progress now)?

Comment: Seems like 3 questions here, usually SE is limited to 1 question per post otherwise it's too broad. Are you able to rephrase your question?

Comment: Here it is. Is it ok now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

go-ethereum (Geth) and pyethereum are clients for interfacing with the Ethereum blockchain. They are 'nodes'.

They implement the [JSON RPC](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC) API specification to allow external clients to pull data from them.

There is no 'official' library for querying a node, but many people use [web3.js](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/). Why? Javascript seems to be the most well developed community when it comes to Ethereum development.

For generating a private key you can use something like [keythereum](https://github.com/ethereumjs/keythereum).

web3.js directly has methods like the `filter` methods for finding transactions matching certain parameters. Have a look at the [API docs](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API).

Comment: Does it mean that I can send json rpc requests to the `localhost:4000` and achive described in question actions?

Comment: If your node is listening on port 4000 then yes.